# In SwiftUI, how to hide keypad automatically using @FocusState and `TextField.focused()` if textField text count cross the given limit

Tags: swiftui

I want to hide keypad automatically after user fill up his phone number (Phone number size 11). and also if user clears 1 or more number, keypad will prompt automatically. For that I create a Custom TextFieldView.

Here is my custom TextField.

`PhoneNumberTextField.swift`

```
struct PhoneNumberTextField: View {
    
    @Binding
    var phoneNumber: String
    
    @Binding
    var isTypingFinished: Bool
    
    @Binding
    var isError: Bool
    
    private var borderColor: Color {
        return isError ? Colors.error : .white
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        HStack(spacing: 15) {

            TextField(
                "মোবাইল নম্বর দিন",
                text: $phoneNumber
            ).onReceive(Just(phoneNumber)) { text in
                let numeric = text.filter { "0123456789".contains($0) }
                if numeric != text {
                    phoneNumber = numeric.limitTo(limit: 11)
                }
                
                phoneNumber = text.limitTo(limit: 11)
                
                if text.count == 11 {
                    isTypingFinished = true
                } else {
                    isTypingFinished = false
                }
            }
            .onFocused(what to do ??) // How too achieve this
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .font(.custom(Fonts.Balooda2_Regular, size: 15))
        }
        .padding(20)
        .background(
            Rectangle().fill(.white)
        )
        .overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .strokeBorder(
                    borderColor,
                    style: StrokeStyle(
                        lineWidth: 1.0
                    )
                )
        )
    }
}
```

And I call this CustomView in my ParentView like bellow

`PhoneNumberView.swift`

```
struct PhoneNumberView: View {
    
    @StateObject
    private var viewModel: AuthenticationViewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()
    
    @State
    var phoneNumber: String = ""
    @State
    var isTypingFinished: Bool = true
        
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0.0) {
                
                Text("Phone number")
                    .font(.custom(Fonts.Balooda2_Regular, size: 14))
                    .foregroundColor(Colors.title3)
                
                Spacer().frame(height: 8)
                
                PhoneNumberTextField(
                    phoneNumber: $phoneNumber,
                    isTypingFinished: $isTypingFinished,
                    isError: $viewModel.isError
                )
                
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.isOtpSent) {
                withAnimation {
                    OtpVerificationView()
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
    }
}
```

This is my ViewModel class

`AuthenticationViewModel.swift`

```
class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isError: Bool = false
    @Published var errorMessage: String = "দয়া করে সঠিক মোবাইল নম্বর ব্যাবহার করুন"
    
    @Published var isOtpValid: Bool = true
    @Published var otpErrorMessage: String = "কোডটি সঠিক নয়, দয়া করে আবার চেষ্টা করো"
    
    @Published var isOtpSent: Bool = false
    
    func isPhoneNumberRegistered(number: String) {
        if isError == true { isError.toggle() }
        
        if number.isPhoneNumberValid() {
            isOtpSent = true
        } else {
            isError = true
            errorMessage = "দয়া করে সঠিক মোবাইল নম্বর ব্যাবহার করুন"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bellow code might be help you...

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
@State var number = ""
@FocusState private var numberIsFocused: Bool
@State var textFieldDisable: Bool = false

let textLimit = 11 //Your limit

var body: some View {
    //Your TextField
    TextField("PhoneNumber", text: $number)
    .focused($numberIsFocused)
    .disabled(textFieldDisable)
    .onReceive(Just(number)) { _ in limitText(textLimit) }
}

//Function to keep text length in limits
func limitText(_ upper: Int) {
    if number.count > upper {
        numberIsFocused = false
        textFieldDisable = true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your approach. By trying your code, my problem is solved pertially. After adding 11 digit , keyboard disapper, But If I want to edit the text again, keyboard will not appear. How toy solve that problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: @AminulHaqueAome For that you have to add .disabled() in TextField. So I have edited my code please check it and let me know if not work.

Comment: bro, may be you didn't understand my case. Image, I fill 11 digit and keypad disappear. That's Great. I want this scenario.But if i want to change the number, I can't add any text as keypad is disappear. How can I solve the issue , I want to give another number. ? Thank in advance